# Looking for manga that the Main Character has no magic but join the magic academy using Science "Magic"

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

So this Character were banished from his family because failing to join academy at a certain age while he has a younger sister which is a genius at magic especially fire magic and going to magic academy real soon. So this MC eventually got a special book from an old man who going to retire after being a librarian for a long time. this book is some kind of a guide to Science which only MC can understand, and because of it he can use "Magic" Science but he has to use the catalyst in order to deal with the lack of mana (use magic stone). then the MC eventualy got to joined the academy after beating his sister in a test using that Science "magic"

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the main character?

Comment: this is black and white manga. this character has black hair, some low ponytail (Kind of like Zhongli style but shorter)